# Node won't start after importing chain history

Tags: error, kiln

I'm following the instructions found here:

https://gitlab.com/obsidian.systems/tezos-bake-monitor/blob/develop/docs/ImportingChainHistory.md

and here:

https://www.tzdutch.com/quicksync/

The kiln node is unable to start and the GUI says "FAILED".

The logs say:

```
01-May-2019 11:16:29LevelWarn""("Process exited unexpectedly:",Id {unId = 1})
01-May-2019 11:16:34LevelError""PublicNodeError_RpcError (RpcError_HttpException "HttpExceptionRequest Request {\n  host                 = \"127.0.0.1\"\
May  1 11:16:40 - node.main: Starting the Tezos node...
May  1 11:16:40 - node.main: No local peer discovery.
May  1 11:16:40 - node.main: Not listening to P2P calls.
May  1 11:16:40 - node.main: Peer's global id: idqzRThCmDPoP7bRETbxVkDwPxFc47
May  1 11:16:40 - node.worker: bootstrapping chain...
tezos-node: Error:
              Permission denied
```

Comment: What does `ls -l ~/.tezos-node/` show?

Comment: `drwx------ 4 kiln kiln 4096 May  2 15:52 NetXdQprcVkpaWU`

Comment: Did you definitely do step 5?
`sudo cp -r ~/.tezos-node/context ~/.tezos-node/store /var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/[chain-id]/
sudo chown -R kiln:kiln /var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/[chain-id]`

Comment: (I assume you are using the debian distro on ubuntu?)

Comment: you were right, I didn't do chown in step 5. I simply unzipped the latest.tar.lz4 file and tried to start the node.

it works now!

I struggled because I don't know llinux and couldn't follow the instructions. the code snippets aren't runnable, I had to edit [chain-id] with NetXdQprcVkpaWU. didn't realize the difference in step 5 of the source/debian instructions.

Answer (score 2):

This comment solved it

> Did you definitely do step 5? sudo cp -r ~/.tezos-node/context ~/.tezos-node/store /var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/[chain-id]/ sudo chown -R kiln:kiln /var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/[chain-id]

This is the answer:

```
sudo chown -R kiln:kiln /var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/[chain-id]
```

or for production:

```
sudo chown -R kiln:kiln /var/lib/kiln/data-dir/tezos-node/NetXdQprcVkpaWU
```

Answer (score 0):

As of v0.6.0 Kiln now supports snapshot import through its user interface, so you should no longer need to manually copy/paste chain history from another node into Kiln's directory.